# Let $\{a_n\}\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Does there exist $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $h^{(n)}(0)=a_n$ for every $n$?

Tags: real-analysis

If the power series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges for all real $x$, then the answer is trivially yes.

If the power series above has radius of convergence $3r>0$, let $\psi_r\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be supported in $[-r,r]$ with $\psi_r(0)=1$ and $\psi_r^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n>0$, and observe that
$$
h(x):=\begin{cases}
\psi_r(x)\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}&\text{if }x\in [-2r,2r],\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
does the job. (For the sake of completeness, I construct such a $\psi_r$ below.)

The case where $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges only at $x=0$ (e.g., if $\{a_n\}$ is something awful like $\{(n!)^2\}$) is the one I'm stuck on.

---

Here we construct the function $\psi_r$ used in the second case above: Define
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\begin{cases}
e^{\frac {-1}{x}}&\text{if }x>0,\\
0&\text{if }x\leq 0
\end{cases}\\
g(x)&=\frac {f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}
\end{align}$$
as in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function). Then
$$\begin{align}
\psi(x)&:=1-g(x)-g(-x)
\end{align}$$
is a $C^\infty$ function with support $[-1,1]$ satisfying $\psi(0)=1$ and $\psi^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n>0$ (this much is clear from the list of properties of $g$ given in the linked article). Take $\psi_r(x)=\psi(x/r)$, and observe that $\psi_r$ does the job.